Import modules from a subfolder
I cannot import modules from a subfolder,where from a subfolder that I am in it;
the folders that I work with, is like this:
Project
   __init__.py
   /objects
      __init__.py
      button.py
      text.py
   /menu
      __init__.py
      main_screen.py

I put the __init__.py file in all of the the folders that containt modules; also using the sys.path.insert does not gonna work and I don't know how to handle the problem
I want import button.py and text.py modules from objects folder, while I am in main_screen.py in menu subfolder.
but when I try this in main_screen.py:
from ..objects.button import Button
from ..objects.text import Text

this error occured:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package 

Does this answer your question? How can I do relative imports in Python?

when you run main_screen.py, its __name__ attribute is set to '__main__'. This doesn't contain a '.', so relative imports can't be used from here. You can add '.../Project' to sys.path and use absolute imports:
import sys

sys.path.append('.../Project')

from objects.button import Button
from objects.text import Text

Alternatively, you can add a __main__.py file to your project path with code like this:
from menu.main_screen import main
main()

This assumes your main_screen.py contains a main function. Note that main_screen.py's __name__ attribute will be set to 'menu.main_screen', so if you use an if __name__ == '__main__': construct, it won't be executed.

I tried the first method sys.path.append(.../Project), which now led me to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objects'.

did you replace '.../Project' with the actual path to your project directory? you need the full path here
